# Angular 2.0 Beta - Access DOM Adapter - BrowserDomAdapter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, typescript, beta

I' currently have a Component in Angular 2.0,
 which tries to use the DOM Adapter API from Angular [BrowserDomAdapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html)
. This DomAdapter will be initialized [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter.ts#L62)

But by default I'm not sure about that, the Dom Adapter need's to be initialized after the Bootstrap is done.

Can someone help / explain me the right usage of the DOM Manipulation in Angular 2.0 Beta?

Answer (score 2):

`DOM` from `angular2/platform/common_dom` should be initialized with an instance of `BrowserDomAdapter` and can be used without injecting.

This works for me in Dart, but in TypeScript it's always uninitialized. I think this is a bug. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904